# PHP - Time Stamp of "First day of next month" at 09:00

Tags: php, time

I need to be able to get the "First day of next month" at a specific time such as 09:00.

I'm using the current function to get the first day of next month:

`strtotime('first day of next month')`

However I need to be able to set a specific time to this also.
The above will give me the time of when i run the command.

Comment: Did you even try `'09:00 first day of next month'` ?

Comment: Ummmm, how about `9am first day of next month`...

Comment: I've not tried that, let me give it a go :)

Comment: If all else fails then you can always brute force the "09:00" in the string https://3v4l.org/3KLDf3

Comment: @CD001 & jeroen I don't have enough power to up-vote but both these worked :D thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
  $datetime=(new DateTime('first day of next month'))->format('Y-m-d 9:00:00'); ?>
```

OR

```
     <?php
       $datetime=(new DateTime('first day of this month'))->format('Y-m-d 9:00:00');

      $time= strtotime($datetime);
     //format('jS, F Y');
      $startDate = time();
       echo "First Day of Next Month :=>".  $result = (date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 month', $time)));

   ?>
```

Comment: Not efficient to convert text to number to text to number. btw, `next month` and not `this  month`.

Comment: Yes, for next month result only and OR   can  do with this :  <?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("first day of next month")) . ' 09:00'; ?>